# Wait until user press enter in textbox in another form and return value

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am new to C# and I'm trying to do sth like this:

```
  myList = list of 1000+ string values;
  1.StartNewThreads(50); //50 is the numbers of new threads
  2.DoSth1(next value from myList);
  3.DoSth2();
  4. var value = {
     ShowNewImageForm(); //show only if not another ImageForm is displayed if another is show - wait
     WaitUntilUserPressEnterInTextBox();
     ReturnValueFormTextbox();
  }
  5.DoSth3();
  6.StartNewThread();
```

For now I have:

```
foreach(String s in myList ) {
 DoSth1(s);  
 DoSth2();     
 DoSth3();    
}
```

And now I'm looking for ideas to points 1,3,6 Can You suggest me how to resolve this?

1. How to start 50 threads
2. How to get value from textbox in another form when user press enter

Comment: This is quite confusing. Are you trying to split your loop into 50 threads? What should the threads do?

Comment: If you have to ask how to start 50 threads, you don't want to do it.

Comment: Why do you want 50 threads? And what is it that they are supposed to be doing exactly?

Comment: You are driving at 100 miles per hour towards a solid concrete wall.  Particularly items 1 and 4 will give you lots of grief.  Do not tackle this project without educating yourself first.  Finding books about threading and GUIs in C# is not a problem.  Or find a school if self-study isn't your thing.

Comment: All threads are independent. At every thread I download html page (s in my code is the url) and then I parse it. I want speed up my app and fetching more pages simulaneously

Comment: @ekapek ...and then you throw away the result?  Or do you need to *use* the value from another thread?

Comment: Yes, after page is downloaded and parsed I return string "Success" or "Error" Threads are independent

Answer (score 0):

For your second question:
Just pass your parent form/owner form in the sub form's constructor and use that reference to pass/set the return value or (more elegant) define a event that will fire on the child form once the user presses the return key and then add an event handler in your parent form.

Answer (score 0):

For start some Threads, you can use a Thread[]

```
    public static void StartThreads(int n)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread[] threads = new System.Threading.Thread[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < threads.Length; i++)
        {
            threads[i] = new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(DoThread));
        }
    }

    public static void DoThread()
    {
        //do some here
    }
```

In the second form you can define this handler:

```
    public static void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            TextBox myText = (TextBox)sender;
            //your code here...
        }
    }
```

Then in the first form:

```
textBox1.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(Form2.textBox1_KeyDown);
```